# SQL Server 2005 Query Statistics

Tags: sql-server, statistics

Where can I find some in-depth information on tuning statistics in SQL Server 2005?

I need to really delve in to what statistics are being used in a number of different queries, how they are interacting with indexes, how/when/where to use custom statistics (over and above what the database tuning advisor recommends), when/how to update the statistics for the best performance etc. etc.

Does anyone know of any good articles/webcasts/books around this subject?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: for the person that voted to close this question because "this belongs on serverfault.com", NO WAY this is a coding question!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you review the following comprehensive Microsoft TechNet reference.

[Statistics Used by the Query Optimizer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc966419.aspx)

Comment: This article provides just the kind of information I'm after, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This book gives fairly detailed information on performance tuning [Inside Microsoft® SQL Server(TM) 2005: Query Tuning and Optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621969)

Comment: @Tom: I highly recommend the entire "Inside SQL Server" series, each volume in the series is invaluable.

Comment: That is a great book, but I couldn't find anything massively detailed about statistics.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you visit http://sqlserverpedia.com/ and look for blog/article/demo/screencast/podcast specific to your needs. SQLServerPedia is a free Premier Online SQL Server resource.

Or are you specifically asking these questions right now:

> "Why is this query running slow? Is my
>   index getting used? Why does this
>   query run faster than this query?"

The book "[Dissecting SQL Server Execution Plans](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1906434026)" will help you on this regard. A free ebook version is available [here](http://www.red-gate.com/specials/Grant.htm?utm_content=Grant080623).

;-)
MarlonRibunal